# (Redux) Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I wanted to deliver the action so I sent the dispatch to the wrong line. But I'm struggling because of this error.

I wrote the code to put in many variables, is this the wrong way?

```
//reducer
export const signUpEmail = email => ({
    type: SIGNUP_EMAIL,
    email,
});

export const signUpInput = ({name, nickname, id, password}) => ({
    type: SIGNUP_INPUT,
    data: {
        name: name,
        nickname: nickname,
        id: id,
        password: password,
    },
});

export const signUpImg = img => ({
    type: SIGNUP_IMG,
    img,
});

const signUpState = {
    email: '',
    data: {
        name: '',
        nickname: '',
        id: '',
        password: '',
    },
    img: '',
};

export const signUpReducer = (state = signUpState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SIGNUP_EMAIL:
            return ({ ...state, email: action.email });
        case SIGNUP_INPUT:
            return ({
                ...state,
                data: {
                    name: action.name,
                    nickname: action.nickname,
                    id: action.id,
                    password: action.password
                },
            });
        case SIGNUP_IMG:
            return ({
                ...state,
                img: action.img,
            });
        default: return state;
    }
};
```

This is reducer

```
//selector  
const {userEmail, name, nickname, id, password, userImg } = useSelector(state => ({
        userEmail: state.email,
            userName: state.name,
            userNickname: state.nickname,
            userId: state.id,
            userPassword: state.password,
        userImg: state.img
    }));
```

This is state connection of store

```
//dispatch 
    const userData = ({userName, userNickname, userId, userPassword}) => {
        dispatch(signUpInput({userName, userNickname, userId, userPassword}));
    }
```

[image]

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're accessing your object children correctly: `state.nickname` should be `state.data.nickname`, `action.nickname` should be `action.data.nickname`, etc.

On a separate note, try to refactor your reducer and split it into different parts based on the current shape of your state. For example, `state.data`, `state.email`, and `state.img` might want to have their own reducers, and you can use `combineReducers` to combine them into a single reducer. It's a bit messy right now.

Comment: Thank you, but there's still an error. This error is not where you answered it. There seems to be a problem with the action creater.